# Is tf.py_func allowed at online prediction time?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Is tf.py_func allowed at online prediction time?
If yes any examples of how to use it?
Does the answer change if I need to install additional pip packages?

My use-case: I work with text, I need to do word stemming (using porter stemmer), I know how to do it using python, tensorflow doesn't have Ops for that. I would like to use the same text processing at training and prediction time - thus I would like to encode it all into a tensorflow graph.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func comes with known limitations and I would like to know if it will work during training and online prediction before I invest more time into it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Py_func can not be restored from a saved model.  However, since your use case involves pre-processing, just invoke the py_func explicitly in all three (train, eval, serving) input functions. This won't work if the py_func is in the middle of your graph, but for stemming, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I confirmed and I do get " 
Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Error loading the model: Failed to load model: Could not load model: Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: Op type not registered 'PyFunc'\n\n (Error code: 0)"" 

I really need to have the same pre-processing at serving time (online prediction time). I change the pre-processing all the time and training and serving pre-processing must match to avoid training-serving skew - so having it persisted with the model is the best way to go.

Comment: Michal, you can have the same pre-processing function. It just won't be automatic. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45665154/5983347 for what I mean.